# Sinch SDK - do not receive old messages

Tags: android, message, sinch

On each logout and then login in of particular user in Sinch SDK I receive old messages directed to that user (also it calls "send" callback with old messages that were send on previous "session").
Is there way to add time-to-live frame for each message or disable this feature?

Currently I add time of sending to each message and if it is longer that X minutes I don't show it, but this is very poor workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi the messages are kept for 30 days, and when you clear a device (i.e uninstall or delete all user files) those messages will be delivered to that device. Its a feature to deliver messages to all devices.

We see it as a great feature to make sure all devices are in sync ;)

If you dont wipe the user files folder then that wont happen in a logout scenario.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I get this is good but... I would be able to turn it off, as well mentioning it in visible place would be nice - to be prepared to handle that scenario.

Comment: Good point, I will ask the product team to add that to the documentation